# Hibernate - Reverse Engineer: Add @GeneratedValue to all @Id fields

Tags: oracle, hibernate, auto-generate

I am attempting to use Hibernate to reverse-engineer an Oracle 11g database.  I would like Hibernate to generate values for my @Id columns, however Oracle 11g does not support identity columns.  Therefor no @GeneratedValue annotations are created when I reverse-engineer the DB.

Is there a way to get the Reverse-Engineering process to automatically include a @GeneratedValue annotation beside each @Id annotation?
E.g.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="identity_sequence")
```

The only way I have been able to find to do this is to include a  entry in my reveng.xml for every single table.  I am trying to avoid that approach due to the number of tables in the database (100s).

I.e.

```
<table name="{table name}">
    <primary-key>
        <generator class="GenerationType.SEQUENCE">
            <param name="sequence">IDENTITY_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
        <key-column name="ID"/>
    </primary-key>
</table>
```

Repeated 100s of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to your question in [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=988711) forum.

Basically you have to provide a [custom reverse engineering strategy](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html#custom-reveng-strategy) class.
There you implement the method `getTableIdentifierStrategyName` which returns the fully qualified name of a class implementing `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator`.
You can use the `identifier` parameter of that method to further restrict the generator class to certain tables.
The example outlined below will use the Sequence Identifier Generator for **all** tables.

```
public class CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {

    public CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    public String getTableIdentifierStrategyName(TableIdentifier identifier) {
        return org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.class.getName();
    }
}
```

Specify that strategy in your JDBCConfiguration reverse engineering task.

```
jdbcconfiguration(propertyfile: "hibernate.properties",
                  packagename: "de.mypackage",
                  reversestrategy: "de.mypackage.CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy",
                  detectManytoMany: true,
                  detectOptimisticLock: false)
```

This will generate the `@GeneratedValue` annotation beside each `@Id` annotation like shown below:

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.SequenceIdentityGenerator")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Warning - this is not an elegant solution**

Using Maven:

1) Reverse Engineer the database normally:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  ...
```

2) Replace the @Id and import with the desired code:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
  ...
  <replacements>
    <replacement>
      <token>@Id</token>
      <value>@Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="identity_sequence")
        @SequenceGenerator(name="identity_sequence",
                            sequenceName="IDENTITY_SEQ", allocationSize=20)
      </value>
    </replacement>
    <replacement>
      <token>import javax.persistence.Id;</token>
      <value>import javax.persistence.Id;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
        import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
      </value>
    </replacement>
```

3) Tidy the generated code:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-java-formatter-plugin</artifactId>
  ...
```

There are a ton of flaws to this solution.  For example, if you have any views (or anything else which doesn't have a numeric primary key) then it doesn't make sense to do the @Id replace.

Hopefully this doesn't remain the best answer for very long.